# "manually" assigning training and testing data

Tags: python, database

I assembled a dataframe, comprised of dates, the weather for said dates, a dummy specifying if there was a forest fire or not, and the area burned for that forest fire.
The problem is that if I use train_test_split, my machine learning models use the whole data, and only 5% of the dates in the dataframe have forest fires, so it tends to train itself into actually predicting that all days won't have fires. Or something, I still don't understand it yet.

Anyways, I believe that if I train the model with only the days containing forest fires, then test it with the whole dataframe, it could predict forest fires better.
Does anyone know how do I go about doing that?
I'm using python 3, and jupyter notebook. I believe RandomForest is best suited for this machine learning problem, too.

Comment: The name of this problem is "class imbalance." See https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/ for several options, or search for other pages talking about how to deal with imbalanced data. Roughly speaking, the options boil down to either removing some records associated with the majority class, or adding new (synthesized / interpolated) records dealing with the minority class, or changing the cutoff where the model output distinguishes between majority & minority. Further guidance requires lots of details about your data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dealing with an imbalanced data set there. There are many ways to go about dealing with it, depending on the data you have available.

If you have a very large data set, you could train your model with nitpicked samples, half with forest fires and half without.

If that is not the case, than you need to go a bit further. You can read more about it [here](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/06/7-techniques-handle-imbalanced-data.html), for instance.